# Use fillType="evenOdd" on Android 21

Tags: android, svg, vector, android-vectordrawable

I have an SVG image that I want to include in an Android project.

The minSdk version for the project is 9. Android Studio is generating PNG files for the SVG.

However, for API 21+, Android studio includes the SVG in a `drawable-anydpi-v21` resource folder.

That means that any device running API 21 and up will use the SVG instead of the PNGs.

And that is the problem: my SVG requires `android:fillType="evenOdd"`.

The PNG are properly generated, but for the SVG, because that attribute is API 24+, it is ignored on API 21 devices, and the image appears filled instead of being a wireframe-like image.

Is there anyway to convince Android studio to only include the PNG and drop the SVG completely?

Is there an other solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried moving your VectorDrawable to a folder named `drawable-anydpi-v24`?

Comment: There is not automated way to convert files that rely on evenOdd to nonZero because that is a visual difference, and a tool would have no idea what it is supposed to look like.  Any conversion would have to be done manually in an editor.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau that's a good idea, although I fear that android studio would interprete that as not generating anything given that the asset is 24+ only. I'll try that to see what it does.

Comment: Any solution fr this one ?

Comment: Can you please show a sample SVG that requires `evenOdd` , and that without it, it will look different? I think it got fixed on later versions of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`

Comment: I don't have access to that file anymore, but in a nutshell evenOdd acts on how fillings are applied. Basically the image looked like a flat full shape instead of an extruded wireframe

Answer (score 8):

Attribute `android:fillType` is only used in API level `24` and higher. For below API level, follow these steps.

1. add this to your Gradle file.

   ```
   //Gradle Plugin 2.0+
   android {
     defaultConfig {
        ...
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
     }
   }
   ```
2. If you are using `ImageView`, change its property `android:src` to `app:srcCompat`.
3. If you are using as `android:drawableStart` or `android:drawableEnd` in `TextView`, change it to `app:drawableStartCompat` or `app:drawableEndCompat`.

Answer (score 7):

**Solution 1**

Flattern image in [Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/) and use [this site](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) to convert SVG to xml for Android

**Solution 2**

I use nonZero instead of evenOdd and open it in Sketch to reverse Order after reverse it will change pathData and remove android:fillType and everything work fine on Android 21+.

**Solution 3**

PNG

TLDR

After some research I found that there are two fill-rule property methods for Vector graphics, SVGs, the “evenodd” vs “nonzero”

I opened the SVG icon in Sketch and inspected the hole at the top of the icon. As expected it uses fill-rule:evenodd property. Now I have to change the fill-rule to use “nonzero” property. How? Select the path. In the right side, there is a settings icon at the “Fills” property. Click it and choose “non-zero”.

From the main menu, choose Layer → Paths → Reverse Order. I got the hole back at the top of the icon and got the hole in the app, too.

[For more detail](https://medium.com/thoughts-overflow/the-mystery-of-the-disappearing-holes-a-gripping-tale-of-using-svg-in-android-442f6035a452)

Comment: you don't have to use nonZero, that's the default value. Reversing it in sketch works, like other solutions that involve modifying the original SVG file, which is not what I am looking for as I'd rather be able to use the files sent by the designer directly.

Comment: After reversed in Sketch it will change pathData and remove android:fillType

Answer (score 3):

SVGs with filltype="evenOdd" seems to work and display properly now with Android gradle plugin 3.2. You may also need to use Support Library 28 or AndroidX 1.0.

Make sure it's at least this version in your top level build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can convert your svg to xml files, that will solve your problem,
Here is the link for converting svg to xml files [svgToXML](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/)

Comment: Thanks. I am converting the SVG to XML, using Vector Asset Studio, which is included in Android Studio. This converter has the same problem: https://github.com/inloop/svg2android/issues/44 and it gave me an XML with `android:fillType="evenOdd"`

Comment: there are several other websites that convert svg to xml, did you tried some of them.

Comment: Did you upload your image or link in svg format, perhaps anyone can convert it.

Comment: I am looking for a more generic solution, as there will be more images of the same kind in the future

Comment: http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/ this one works a lot better for me. It does not support batch, but sometimes the result differed from the original SVG. Did not have it with this converter yet though, opposed to the one mentioned in the answer

Comment: SVG's are automatically converted to XML by Android Studio import

Answer (score -1):

Convert your SVG file [online](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/), then remove `android:fillType="evenOdd"` in the generated xml file. Copy and paste the xml file in the `res/drawable` folder. Use it.
Hope this helps!