# Android library vector converted to png and Kotlin files obfuscated by default

Tags: android, kotlin, android-library

I just create a new android project with Android Studio(AS). I add a `library module` with a vector drawable and a Kotlin file with comments.
I run assemble release and it generates an `aar` file.

I open this aar release file with AS decompiler and I see the vector file is converted to png for different drawables and the Kotlin file is obfuscated saying `compiled code`.

The original xml vector file can be found only in directory `drawable-anydpi-v24`

How can I disable `vector to png` and `file obfuscation` for my library module?

I have default build.gradle: `minifyEnabled false`

(I am already aware of `org.jetbrains.dokka` so please don't say just use it)

Comment: what's your minSdkVersion? are you setting `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary` in build.gradle? pngs are generated to [support vectors on devices running platform versions lower than Android 5.0](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources#vector-drawables-backward-solution) so they shouldn't be generated if you don't support API 21 or have `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`

Comment: @Gustavo thanks for your comment it made me investigate more in this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Gustavo comment in my question I started investigating even more regarding the issue with generated png files.

I have the min sdk 21, I tried also 22 and it had the same result.
Then after some playing with vectors I find out that what caused my issue was the property `android:fillType="evenOdd"`

I tested with this property and without it and I had these 2 results:

Source xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="80dp"
android:height="228dp"
android:alpha="0.81"
android:viewportWidth="99"
android:viewportHeight="284">

<path
    android:fillAlpha="0.9"
    android:fillColor="#33B8E3"
    android:strokeLineJoin="round"
    android:strokeLineCap="round"
    android:strokeColor="#000"
    android:strokeAlpha="0.9"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:fillType="evenOdd" // removing this line
    android:pathData="M49.5 112.842c25.366 0 48.654-27.702 48.654-57.745C98.154 25.054 76.371 0.7 49.5 0.7 22.63 0.7 0.846 25.054 0.846 55.097s23.287 57.745 48.654 57.745z" />

</vector>
```

I had these 2 results for the aar build:

*without the fill type value*
[image: without the fill type value]

*with fill type value*
[image: with fill type value]

After that I find this [question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188944/use-filltype-evenodd-on-android-21)

After I set the `minSdk` to 24, the png files are not generated anymore.

I can not work with minSdk so low currently but at least I know what is causing it.